# Unhandled exception at Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to write a simple reverse string program and getting the above error. I am unable to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
void reverse(char *str) {
char *end, *begin;
end = str;
begin = str;

while (*end != '\0') {
    end++;
}

    end--;

char temp;

while (begin < end) {
    temp = *begin;
    *begin++ = *end; //This is the line producing the error
    *end-- = temp;
}
}

void main() {
char *str = "welcome";
reverse(str);
}
```

Need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to modify a string literal, which is undefined behavior. This would be a valid way of declaring `str` in `main` if you wanted to modify it:

```
char str[] = "welcome";
```

Also, you are assigning `end` to the beginning of `str` and then you are doing this:

```
end--;
```

which decrements the pointer to before the memory allocated for the string, which is undefined behavior. My guess it you meant to do this:

```
end = str+ (strlen(str)-1);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy some code, I'll update it now (before the end--)

Comment: Your solution helped. I had to initialize the string this way and the program worked. Thank you.